# How to resolve errors when using 'Dictionary'

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm creating a Class to handle registry entries for my application, but I'm getting some problems early on.

In the below, it should take all of the keys/values for a SubKey and add them to a `Dictonary`. The message box that is commented out shows the keys and values correctly, but every time the function is run the line below generates an error `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`.

As the registry keys themselves seem to be fine, I think it's to do with the way I'm using the `RegKeys Dictonary`. If someone could take a look and advise I'd be grateful. Thanks.

This is how I'm initiating the Class (I haven't even tried to do anything else just yet) -

```
Private Sub getMyRegSettings()

        Dim ServerPing As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("ServerPing")
        Dim Servers As RegistryKey = ServerPing.OpenSubKey("Servers")
        Dim MyRegistry As New MyRegistry(Servers)
        Dim RegKeys As Dictionary(Of String, String) = MyRegistry.RegKeys

End Sub
```

And here is the Class that is causing me some trouble -

```
Public Class MyRegistry

    Public RegKeys As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Sub New(SubKey As RegistryKey)

        get_registry_keys(SubKey)

    End Sub

    Private Sub get_registry_keys(SubKey As RegistryKey)

        ' Print the information from the Test9999 subkey.
        For Each valueName As String In SubKey.GetValueNames() ' Error occurs here

            'MsgBox("Key: " & valueName & vbCrLf & "Value: " & SubKey.GetValue(valueName))
            RegKeys(valueName) = SubKey.GetValue(valueName).ToString()

        Next valueName

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Where do you create a new instance of RegKeys inside MyRegistry? In the constructor you don't and in get_registry_keys you use it when it's still Null.

Comment: Doesn't declaring it as a property of the Class create it? I've done that directly under `Public Class MyRegistry`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initialising your `RegKeys` Object

Try changing this line:

```
Public RegKeys As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

to this:

```
Public RegKeys As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

This will ensure the dictionary is initialised when the class is created

Comment: @DavidGard - No problem. Please remember to upvote any answers that helped you and mark the appropriate answer as the solution.

Comment: I'm on it, don't you worry. It won't let me mark them as answered until after x number of minutes though, so had to wait and come back in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Public RegKeys As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

declares a variable of Dictionary type (a reference type) but this variable is not an instance of a Dictionary. To become a valid instance you need to instantiate with new

```
Public RegKeys = new Dictionary(Of String, String)
```